# Return a dictionary with keys that are the first letter of a word and lists of those words?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I want to write a function that takes a list of words and keys and outputs those keys as dictionary keys with any words starting with that letter attached.
How could this be achieved using simple python 3 code?

eg. takes `(['apples', 'apple', 'bananna', 'fan'], 'fad')`

returns `{'a' : ['apple', 'apples'], 'f' : ['fan']}`

so far i have tried:

```
def dictionary(words, char_keys)
char_keys = remove_duplicates(char_keys)
ret = {}
keys_in_dict = []
words = sorted(words)
for word in words:
    if word[0] in char_keys and word[0] not in keys_in_dict:   
        ret[word[0]] = word
        keys_in_dict.append(word[0])
    elif word[0] in keys_in_dict:
        ret[word[0]] += (word)
return ret
```

This gives kinda the right output but it the output is in a single string rather than a list of strings.(the def is not indented properly i know)

Comment: Post an attempt at solving the exercise with code.

Comment: Please clarify if the input can only be a list or an iterable which contains lists and strings.

Answer (score 2):

If the input is a list of strings, you can check if the char is in the dict, if yes, append the word, otherwise add a list with the word:

```
def dictionary(inpt):
    result = {}
    for word in inpt:
        char = word[0]
        if char in result:
            result[char].append(word)
        else:
            result[char] = [word]
    return result
```

The modern way to do this is to use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `list` as argument.

```
def dictionary(inpt):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for word in inpt:
        result[word[0]].append(word)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your list of inputs are consisted with only strings or it can also include sub-lists of strings (and I'm not so sure why "fad" disappeared in your example). Obviously, in the latter scenario it will need some more effort. For simplicity I assume if contains only strings and here's a piece of code which hopefully points the direction:

```
d = {}
for elem in input_list[0]:
    if elem[0] in input_list[1]
        lst = d.get(elem[0], [])
        lst.append(elem)
        d[elem] = lst
```

Comment: f, a and d were dictionary keys. because d had no words to assign to, i dont really want it there. I'll post what i have now.

Comment: My bad, didn't read your OP carefully. See the modified code - you simply need to test if elem[0] is in your key list.